# Remove Successors for each BB

Tags: llvm

I need to remove successors from every basic block to insert new ones

I tried this code, but it doesn't work

```
void RemoveSuccessor(TerminatorInst *TI, unsigned SuccNum) {
    assert(SuccNum < TI->getNumSuccessors() &&
            "Trying to remove a nonexistant successor!");

    // If our old successor block contains any PHI nodes, remove the entry in the
    // PHI nodes that comes from this branch...
    //
    BasicBlock *BB = TI->getParent();
    TI->getSuccessor(SuccNum)->removePredecessor(BB);

    TerminatorInst *NewTI = 0;
    switch (TI->getOpcode()) {
        case Instruction::Br:
            // If this is a conditional branch... convert to unconditional branch.
            if (TI->getNumSuccessors() == 2) {
                cast<BranchInst>(TI)->setUnconditionalDest(TI->getSuccessor(1-SuccNum));
            } else {                    // Otherwise convert to a return instruction...
                Value *RetVal = 0;

                // Create a value to return... if the function doesn't return null...
                if (!(BB->getParent()->getReturnType())->isVoidTy())
                    RetVal = Constant::getNullValue(BB->getParent()->getReturnType());
                // Create the return...
                NewTI = 0;
            }
            break;

        case Instruction::Invoke:    // Should convert to call
        case Instruction::Switch:    // Should remove entry
        default:
        case Instruction::Ret:       // Cannot happen, has no successors!
            assert(0 && "Unhandled terminator instruction type in RemoveSuccessor!");
            abort();
    }

    if (NewTI)   // If it's a different instruction, replace.
        ReplaceInstWithInst(TI, NewTI);
}
```

Example of the results:

```
if.then:                                          ; preds = %for.inc, %entry, %for.body
```

`preds` should not include `%for.body` according to remove the successors of `%for.body` before inserting the new successors

Comment: "It doesn't work" - what is the exact failure? Compile error? Malformed module? Crash? Also, I'm assuming you mean "it doesn't work on a `BranchInst`", since you don't have implementations for switch yet, is that correct?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at how the terminator at `%for.body` looks like to help identify what went wrong... you can also paste it here.

Comment: Sorry for late reply , `  br i1 %cmp1, label %if.then, label %if.else` This is the terminator, According to that how to change the terminator to get the new successors??

Comment: I think that this is done if I use `addDestination` as you told me before in `indirectBranch`

Answer (score 0):

Beyond my comment above asking for clarifications, this line seems fishy:

```
cast<BranchInst>(TI)->setUnconditionalDest(TI->getSuccessor(1-SuccNum));
```

From what I know the `setUnconditionalDest()` method have been removed *years* ago, what version are you using? In any case, I recommend creating a **new** unconditional `BranchInst`, then using `ReplaceInstWithInst()` to replace the conditional one.

Comment: This one solves one of the problems, but not all of it. According to revising the .ll file I found that predecessors have one or more from the old basic blocks. Do you think there is something also missing??

Comment: @R.Omar I didn't quite understand that comment... plus, you still didn't provide the precise error you are getting. Can you perhaps edit your question to include that information?